# i cant found location services .API in my android studio map

Tags: android

```
 mGoogleApi= new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
              .addApi(Locationservices.API);// i cant found LocationServices.API
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
}
```

to your gradle file